# cmd / batch file not showing nor logging output of other programs in order

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo

I have this script in a Windows cmd file which does what I want to. It also shows and logs its output, but apparently the output of the programs used inside that script are not shown nor logged in order. 
See the script and output below.

```
@ECHO OFF
:: script global variables 
SET log=nslookup-tests.log

::Logic
set LF=^



REM The two empty lines abive are required!!
set output=****%date% %time% -- NSLOOKUP from anywhere with DNS server from edpnet****
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set output=!output!!LF!!LF!!LF!**youtube.com
set output=!output!!LF!!LF!*edpnet DNS
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('nslookup youtube.com 212.71.0.33') do (
 set output=!output!!LF!%%f
)
set output=!output!!LF!!LF!*google DNS
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('nslookup youtube.com 8.8.8.8') do (
 set output=!output!!LF!%%f
)

set output=!output!!LF!!LF!!LF!**bestofyoutube.com
set output=!output!!LF!!LF!*edpnet DNS
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('nslookup bestofyoutube.com 212.71.0.33') do (
 set output=!output!!LF!%%f
)
set output=!output!!LF!!LF!*google DNS
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('nslookup bestofyoutube.com 8.8.8.8') do (
 set output=!output!!LF!%%f
)

set output=!output!!LF!!LF!!LF!**vidzi.tv
set output=!output!!LF!!LF!*edpnet DNS
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('nslookup vidzi.tv 212.71.0.33') do (
 set output=!output!!LF!%%f
)
set output=!output!!LF!!LF!*google DNS
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('nslookup vidzi.tv 8.8.8.8') do (
 set output=!output!!LF!%%f
)

::output to screen and append to log file
echo !output!
echo !output!!LF!!LF!!LF!!LF! >> "!log!"

::Keep window open
cmd /k
```

Output:

```
****wo 23/12/2015    9:46:18,94 -- NSLOOKUP from anywhere with DNS server from edpnet****

Non-authoritative answer:
Non-authoritative answer:
Non-authoritative answer:
Non-authoritative answer:
Non-authoritative answer:
Non-authoritative answer:
****do 24/12/2015 14:49:32,90 -- NSLOOKUP from anywhere with DNS server from edpnet****


**youtube.com

*edpnet DNS
Server:  dns01.edpnet.net
Address:  212.71.0.33
Name:    youtube.com
Addresses:  2a00:1450:4013:c00::5d
    173.194.65.190
    173.194.65.136
    173.194.65.93
    173.194.65.91

*google DNS
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8
Name:    youtube.com
Addresses:  2a00:1450:400c:c07::5b
    85.234.204.215
    85.234.204.236
    85.234.204.251
    85.234.204.226
    85.234.204.237
    85.234.204.211
    85.234.204.245
    85.234.204.230
    85.234.204.241
    85.234.204.222
    85.234.204.221
    85.234.204.207
    85.234.204.249
    85.234.204.219
    85.234.204.234


**bestofyoutube.com

*edpnet DNS
Server:  dns01.edpnet.net
Address:  212.71.0.33
Name:    bestofyoutube.com
Address:  104.238.110.149

*google DNS
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8
Name:    bestofyoutube.com
Address:  104.238.110.149


**vidzi.tv

*edpnet DNS
Server:  dns01.edpnet.net
Address:  212.71.0.33
Name:    vidzi.tv
Addresses:  46.17.100.122
    46.28.202.183
    82.115.15.12

*google DNS
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8
Name:    vidzi.tv
Addresses:  82.115.15.12
    46.28.202.183
    46.17.100.122
```

The output's order is somewhat ordered, but there are a bunch of `Non-authoritative answer:` that appear on top and not in the log file. They don't get appended to the output variable it seems.

Are programs executed one after the order without waiting for it to finish? It seems like asynchronous behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **stdout** for standard output messages and **stderr** for error messages.

`Non-authoritative answer` is an error message written to **stderr**.

Command **for** processes by default only messages written to **stdout**.

It would be perhaps much easier [using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) and redirect **stdout** and **stderr** directly to log file instead of collecting all message lines in an environment variable and finally write the value of the environment variable to log file.

However, redirecting **stderr** of **nslookup** to **stdout** in each **for** loop using `2>&1` with escaping angle bracket and ampersand with `^` to get `2>&1` applied to **nslookup** instead of command **for** would solve your problem.

```
@echo off
:: script global variables
set log=nslookup-tests.log

::Logic
set LF=^



REM The two empty lines above are required!!

set output=****%date% %time% -- NSLOOKUP from anywhere with DNS server from edpnet****
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set output=!output!!LF!!LF!!LF!**youtube.com
set output=!output!!LF!!LF!*edpnet DNS
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('nslookup youtube.com 212.71.0.33 2^>^&1') do (
    set output=!output!!LF!%%f
)
set output=!output!!LF!!LF!*google DNS
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('nslookup youtube.com 8.8.8.8 2^>^&1') do (
    set output=!output!!LF!%%f
)

set output=!output!!LF!!LF!!LF!**bestofyoutube.com
set output=!output!!LF!!LF!*edpnet DNS
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('nslookup bestofyoutube.com 212.71.0.33 2^>^&1') do (
    set output=!output!!LF!%%f
)
set output=!output!!LF!!LF!*google DNS
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('nslookup bestofyoutube.com 8.8.8.8 2^>^&1') do (
    set output=!output!!LF!%%f
)

set output=!output!!LF!!LF!!LF!**vidzi.tv
set output=!output!!LF!!LF!*edpnet DNS
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('nslookup vidzi.tv 212.71.0.33 2^>^&1') do (
    set output=!output!!LF!%%f
)
set output=!output!!LF!!LF!*google DNS
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('nslookup vidzi.tv 8.8.8.8 2^>^&1') do (
    set output=!output!!LF!%%f
)

::output to screen and append to log file
echo !output!
echo !output!!LF!!LF!!LF!!LF! >> "!log!"

::Keep window open
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /k
```

Here is your code redirecting **stderr** and **stdout** directly to a log file.

```
@echo off
:: script global variables
set "log=nslookup-tests.log"

(
    echo ****%date% %time% -- NSLOOKUP from anywhere with DNS server from edpnet****
    echo.
    echo.
    echo **youtube.com
    echo.
    echo *edpnet DNS
    %SystemRoot%\System32\nslookup.exe youtube.com 212.71.0.33
    echo *google DNS
    %SystemRoot%\System32\nslookup.exe youtube.com 8.8.8.8

    echo.
    echo **bestofyoutube.com
    echo.
    echo *edpnet DNS
    %SystemRoot%\System32\nslookup.exe bestofyoutube.com 212.71.0.33
    echo *google DNS
    %SystemRoot%\System32\nslookup.exe bestofyoutube.com 8.8.8.8

    echo.
    echo **vidzi.tv
    echo.
    echo *edpnet DNS
    %SystemRoot%\System32\nslookup.exe vidzi.tv 212.71.0.33
    echo *google DNS
    %SystemRoot%\System32\nslookup.exe vidzi.tv 8.8.8.8
    echo.
) >"%TEMP%\%log%" 2>&1

rem Output to screen and append new log to previous log.
type "%TEMP%\%log%"
type "%TEMP%\%log%">>"%log%"
del "%TEMP%\%log%"

::Keep window open
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /k
```